# iOS: Is it ok to store a RSA private key (use to decrypt text) in your application document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory, rsa

I want the user to use their RSA private key via file sharing to store in my App's document directory. It is ok if the user has access to the RSA private key, but I don't want anyone else to have access to it. Is this a good idea and if not how can I get the user's to store his/her RSA private key in my App securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `keychain` to store sensitive information like private keys.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/KeyManagementAPIs/KeyManagementAPIs.html

Do not attempt to roll your own solution ... iOS has already done the hard work for you (~properly).

Using the `keychain` will protect your data from other apps.

---

If you want to do this for OS X rather that iOS, then take a look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-TP9

Comment: Is there a way to transfer the private key from the user's desktop to the iPhone/iPad keychain? Sorry, my last comment wasn't accurate on what I wanted.

Comment: Lol! No worries :0) It seems that you can do this manually ... http://www.icreatemagazine.com/tips/os-x-tutorial-how-to-transfer-keychain-data-between-macs/ ... or by using iCloud `keychain` ... https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14405?locale=en_US ... but you need to ask another question as to how to go about that!

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the insight. I was hoping the directory will be sufficient (technically it works), but it looks like I need to go with keychain.

Comment: Good choice! There's probably a bit of learning to do but it will be worth it in the long run! The general rule with computer security is don't implement it yourself :0)